# No nordeste do Brasil, qual siginificado da expressão "comigo a volta é por dentro"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões-idiomáticas, regionalismo

No filme o Auto da Compadecida, o personagem Chicó diz o seguinte:

> Porque comigo a volta é por dentro, que nem pavio de vela em talo de macaxeira.

A julgar pelo contexto ([veja aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=spcSDgqJlWc&feature=youtu.be&t=95)), a expressão "comigo a volta é por dentro" seria equivalente a "comigo o buraco é mais embaixo".

1) Esta interpretação está correta?

2) Essa é uma expressão de uso corrente no nordeste do Brasil? Ou aparece apenas no filme? (Pergunto isso porque não consegui achar na internet uma referência com o significado desta expressão.)

3) Na região em que a expressão é utilizada, pra que serve um "pavio de vela em talo de macaxeira"? E por que num pavio de vela em talo de macaxeira a volta é "por dentro"?

Comment: Nunca ouvi essa expressão aqui na região sudeste, mas eu entenderia como "comigo o buraco é mais embaixo", conforme citado na pergunta.

Comment: Bem o grande [Ariano Suassuna](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariano_Suassuna) era do interior da Paraíba, quando escreveu o livro, que deu origem ao filme, usou e abusou de expressões pitorescas. Eu que sou Nordestino mas de cidade grande não lembro de ter ouvido essa expressão

Comment: @jean Me parece que essa cena não existe no livro. Então, essa fala foi criada apenas para o filme ou então foi tirada de alguma outra obra do Ariano.

Answer (score 8):

Bem. Eu também fiquei curioso. Não sou nordestino, mas conheço vários e fiz umas perguntas. As pessoas que falaram ter ouvido a expressão, não afirmaram com tanta certeza. Mas então vamos lá...

1) Realmente a expressão "comigo a volta é por dentro" seria equivalente a "comigo o buraco é mais embaixo".

2) Encontrei a expressão num livro, porém acredito que este seja mais recente que o filme. Então o termo para o livro pode ter vindo do filme.

No livro **A Quarta Guerra Servil II - A Odisseia da Caçada** - *Rosa — capítulo 4*

Podemos ler:

> — Eu tô ligada o que cê tava dizendo, rapaz. - disse Rosa, agora séria
>   e transparecendo apenas frieza e perigo na voz – Sei como é o papinho
>   do teu tipo. E ó, pra você que fica me comediando, só digo que já vi
>   guri buchudo mais home que tu, e que teu mundinho à toa não vale o
>   cinto que segura tua calça. Então te cuida, porque muita mulher que
>   nem eu te dobra ao meio e te derruba. Home sem culhão que nem você cai
>   fácil, então fica na boa, que comigo a volta é por dentro.
>
> Rosa disse com firmeza que até surpreendeu os dois homens. Certamente não estavam
>   acostumados a ser respondidos dessa maneira por mulher alguma, quanto
>   mais por uma "novinha" baiana qualquer.

3) "pavio de vela em talo de macaxeira"?

No centro do miolo de uma macaxeira há uma parte dura, que lembra o pavio de uma vela. Algo que incomoda, 'difícil' de tirar e que dá uma trabalheira.

Answer (score 2):

Sempre entendi esse expressão como: que nem pavio de vela, e talo de macacheira. Porque tanto o pavio da vela, como o talo da macacheira, seguem um caminho reto, sem volta, sem arrodeio. Acho que ele quis dizer que: a conversa seria reta, direta.

Comment: Nesse caso, qual seria a comparação com "a volta é por dentro"?

Answer (score 1):

"Comigo a volta é por dentro": É que nao tem voltas, "arrodeio", "rudeio", ENROLAÇAO. Equivalente no Sudeste a "meter um papo reto", "Ir direto ao ponto"; "Palavra minha nao faz curva não".
O "pavio de vela" e o "talo de macaxeira" são para elucidar coisas que são "por dentro" também. (Fonte: Norte de Minas - Gerazeiro - vivendo no Nordeste e Sudeste ao mesmo tempo).

Comment: Acácio, bem-vindo ao site. Se eu compreendi bem, a explicação tem lógica: o pavio da vela e o talo da macaxeira são retos, não dão voltas. Mas então a expressão completa é "comigo a volta é por dentro como o pavio de vela e talo da macaxeira"? Porque só com "comigo a volta é por dentro" não se compreende que é reto (sem voltas). Ou as pessoas só precisam de dizer "comigo a volta é por dentro" porque as pessoas do Nordeste já sabem o resto?

Comment: "comigo a volta é por dentro, que nem pavio de vela e talo de macaxeira" . A expressão "que nem"  usamos por aqui para subistiur "como o", "Igual a". etc.  - "Amarga qui nem jiló" Luiz Gonzaga.

Answer (score 1):

Sou do interior do Sul da Bahia e atualmente moro na Paraíba. Mas acredito que a frase tem mais a ver com o sentido de “Vou direto ao ponto, sem fazer arrudeios”. Seria o oposto de “comer pelas beiradas”. Paraibanos são diretos e objetivos.

Answer (score 0):

Fazer uma volta por dentro em uma corrida é complicado/difícil. E colocar um pavio de vela em talo de macaxeira também. Acredito que a relação seja essa.

"Vai conhecer o que é o macho, porque comigo a volta é por dentro" - comigo é complicado

"que nem pavio de vela em talo de macaxeira" - igual a pavio de vela...

Também existe a seguinte hipótese: fazer uma volta por dentro, apesar de ser mais difícil, é algo mais rápido/direto/objetivo/agressivo e te favorece em uma corrida. Também podemos pensar nessa relação dessa maneira, com ele o negócio é direto/objetivo que nem o pavio de vela etcc

Comentando agora empolgado com o anúncio do 2 rsrs

Answer (score -1):

Na verdade a expressão é  "comigo a volta é por dentro" , aqui chicó compara a pavio de vela e a talo de macaxeira , pois ambos tbm são por dentro .

Comment: Mas compara o quê?